# Implementation of or in foldr and foldl' in Data.List

Tags: haskell

Here is the declaration of `or` function from Prelude

```
or = foldr (||) False
```

This implementation is fine if the list fields contains at least one `True`
If the list contains all `False` then overflow can happen and  We have to reduce till last element

Here is the implementation using foldl'

```
or = foldl' (||) False
```

Here though it is inefficient since it has to reduce till last element of the list irrespective of the contents of the list argument. But we are guaranteed that we will not encounter an overflow.

So question is why not use the safer `foldl'` version

Comment: What do you mean by "overflow can happen". Should or supposed to be traverse the whole list to see if anything is True?

Comment: If the list argument contain all `False` then we need to tarverse the whole list to check. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @utdemir has the point, you must check it till the last element if all the previus ones are False

Comment: @user634615, Yes, otherwise you would never know it the last element is  true

Comment: @user634615: No you're correct about the traversing. But `(||)` isn't strict in its arguments, other than, let's say `(+)`, where you can get into problems. Therefore, your stack overflow does not happen in `or`.

Comment: in case of `foldr` till we get `True` we are building up thunks. Is'nt it?

Comment: well ask yourself this question : which one will work for `True : repeat False`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the list contains all `False` then […] We have to reduce till last element.

That is correct.

> If the list contains all `False` then overflow can happen […].

That's not. Other than functions like `(+)`, `(||)` isn't strict in *both* arguments. It only pattern matches the left one:

```
(||) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
(||) True _ = True
(||) _    x = x
```

Therefore, if we use the definition of `foldr` for lists, we get:

```
foldr (||) False [False,False])
  = False || (foldr (||) False [False]) -- use: False || x = x
  = foldr (||) False [False]
  = False || (foldr (||) False [])      -- use: False || x = x
  = foldr (||) False []
  = False
```

However, if we use a function where *both* arguments need to be fully evaluated we get into problems:

```
foldr (+) 0 [1,2]
  = 0 + (foldr (+) 1 [2])  -- cannot reduce (+), since it needs right hand side
  = 0 + (1 + (foldr (+) 2 []))
  = 0 + (1 + (2))
  = 0 + (3)
  = 3
```

Which is why you should use `foldl'` in this case. But for right-lazy functions like `(||)` or `(:)`, `foldr` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Got it. I didn't pay attention to definition of (||)

Comment: `foldr strictOr` runs in constant space (no "overflow") as well. `strictOr` can be defined by pattern matching or simply `\x y -> x \`seq\` y \`seq\` x || y`. Maybe there is some super special optimization going on here but I think this property is due to `foldr` itself.

Comment: @user2407038: IIRC, GHC doesn't use above `foldr` implementation, but one that's based on builders. That being said, `foldr strictOr` fails when interpreted in GHCi on large lists like `replicate (10^9) False`. I'm not sure whether optimization rules (aka possible builders) defuse that.